# No Navigation No Exception

Tags: java, jsf

A form in an xhtml page:

```
<h:form>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="gender" required="true"
                requiredMessage="#{msg['field.email.REQUIRED']}"
                value="#{registerController.gender}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{registerController.genders}" var="gender"
                    itemLabel="#{gender}" itemValue="#{gender}"></f:selectItems>
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <p:commandButton value="Cont"
                action="#{registerController.genderEntered()}" />
            <h:link value="Back" outcome="/view/login.xhtml" />

        </h:form>
```

RegisterController.java

```
public String genderEntered(){
        return "email.xhtml";
    }
```

I delete required="true" but the problem continues.
There is no exception but navigation do not go to email.xhtml

Comment: Have you tried with h:commandButton instead of p:commandButton?

Comment: @Sanz this depends on what `h` and `p` are mapped to, don't you think?

Comment: @tuxi how does `registerController` variable get propagated onto the jsp?

Comment: @maksimov if i understand you right RegisterController is a javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean and i describe its instance name in annotation @ManagedBean(name = "registerController")

Comment: A more detailed problem description and a precise question title would help to narrow down the problem. Please provide the following information: 1. Is your action method called at all? 2. Does it work if you have only the button inside the form?

Comment: @tuxi not very familiar with @ManagedBean but likewise not sure you can call methods like this. Why not to try to rename your `RegisterController#genderEntered()` to `RegisterController#getGenderEnteredURL()` and modify your action to `action="#{registerController.genderEnteredURL}"`. I.e. use it as a property (like it should be).

Comment: try removing the .xhtml extension from the return value of genderEntered

Comment: thanks i should specify more detail sorry. @Sanz when i replace the p:commandButton to h:commandButton i see an exception thanks.

Comment: @MattHandy i found out there is a problem in destination xhtml file thanks

Comment: @maksimov: you're wrong.

Comment: @BalusC care to elaborate? :)

Comment: @maksimov: read a basic JSF tutorial.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't have any issues with my JSF. I hope you know a difference between trying to help and trying to lecture.